# How to target another value of the same object?

Tags: php, json

I have an object:

```
{
    "id": "GRP-25",
    "text": "All Areas",
    "groupid": 0,
    "leaf": false,
    "qtip": "Common",
    "link": null,
    "helplink": null,
},
```

Here I'm changing the value of `ID` but I'm trying to change it only if `leaf` is `true`. How do I target the value of a `leaf` into the if statement?

```
array_walk_recursive($result, function (&$v, $k) { 
    if($k == 'id'){ 
        $v ='GRP-'.$v; 
    }    
});
```

Comment: Do you have nested objects ? You could share a little bit more data of `$result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_walk_recursive` cannot know the value of `leaf`. You could create a recursive function to change the value of `id` from the `leaf` value:

```
function changeLeafId(array &$data)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) 
    {
        // recursive call 
        if (is_array($v)) {
            changeLeafId($data[$k]);
            continue;
        }

        // update 'id' from 'leaf'
        if ($k == 'id' && $data['leaf'] ?? false) {
            $data[$k] = 'GRP-' . $v;
        }
    }
}

changeLeafId($result);
```

You can see the result with sample data : https://3v4l.org/Ss584

Comment: This is good but I'm also trying to add for the leafs that have the value true. They should have different prefix but adding another if statement isn't working `elseif ($k == 'id' && $data['leaf'] ?? true) {
            $data[$k] = 'APP-' . $v;
        }`

Comment: NB: in `$data['leaf'] ?? false`, `false` is the default value if `$data['leaf']` is not set.

Comment: So, `$data['leaf'] ?? false` means, that is `$data['leaf']` is true, the condition, is validated. and `GRP-` is prefixed. See the linked demo.

Comment: Never mind, I changed it to `if ($k == 'id' && $data['leaf'] === true)` and it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do that with array walk, I would be inclined to use a foreach

something along these lines

```
foreach ($results as &$result) {
  if ($result->leaf == true) {
    $result->id = 'GRP-'.$result->id; 
  }
}
```

Assuming here you did json_decode as objects, otherwise if you are doing json_decode as arrays, then you will need to change the -> to []

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't go recursively only the first parent.